# Photo Moving Violation Tickets in DC

Tags: united-states, traffic

I was driving my Out of State car in DC last year ( actually the car is in my Wife's Name but we are both listed as drivers on the Insurance Policy) when a Photo Camera issued 2 tickets for moving violations (11 to 15 miles over limit). I paid the fines ONLINE.

Will DC DMV report the violations to my Home State DMV?

If yes how would they know who was driving? I do not want anything on my wife's driving record. My Home state starts suspending license at 4 moving violations

Will they report it to my Insurance company?

Is this violation (11 - 15 over limit) considered minor?

Is there something I can do proactively?

Answer (score 3):

I live in MD near DC, and have been ticketed by the cameras in both DC and MD. At least for speeding and red-light violations (and I think for all camera detected violations) these are just fines, not true moving violations in that no license points are assessed, and there is no impact on insurance, provided the ticket is paid, unlike what would have happened had an officer written the ticket in person. One can contest the ticket, but it is not likely to be worth the time and trouble.

This policy of not assessing points is precisely because there is no assured way of determining who the driver is with current technology, although cameras that can see the driver through the windshield and match him or her against a database by facial recognition may be coming. Currently a human reviews the images in an effort to rule out false positives and certify that an actual violation is shown. The name and title of this person is shown on the notice I get, at least from MD.

What one can do "proactively":

1. do not speed or go through red lights
2. pay all camera tickets promptly (or file the paperwork to contest them). If unpaid beyond the deadline they turn into more serious violations that do carry points, just like failing to attend a court date.